# Dropdown select option pagination in angular 2

Tags: angular, pipe, karma-jasmine, angular2-directives

I need to create a dynamic table with pagination. But I want to create a drop down with select option a “Show 50, 100, All” with next and previous buttons.

Comment: please show us your code and what problem occurs in your code, it will be a lot easier to solve the question that way

Comment: I have used ngx-pagination dependency that works for pagination ,but i am looking for sdropdown select option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change itemsPerPage to be set to a variable. Set the initial value to whatever you think is best. Then you can add https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-dropdown and set the dropdown values to the 50 100 etc. You could also wrap the pagination with an ngIf* so that if the value is 'all' pagination is ignored and all rows are shown.

Or if you have some flexibility I would recommend primeNg:
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/paginator

Comment: Thanks, will look into it.

Comment: If that works you should accept the answer, if not please provide additional details/ update. Thanks.